# How to route from page to another in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can i pass prop to another another component while redirecting from one page to another.

When i click on View Button i want to pass `details` state to another component i.e {PAGING} which will open on a new page.

I am trying to open PAGING component on new page with url `<Route path="/detilaing" exact component={PAGING} />`

On button click i want the tab and clicked button details only and hide other parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to update

- Your Router component should be placed at top level

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Combined />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

- since you wish to pass in just params you may wish to persist it on refreshes too. In such a case, its a good idea to actually pass it as params in route

```
<Route path="/detilaing/:ability" exact component={PAGING} />
```

- Now you can use `useHistory` within your Movement component to get history object and call `history.push`. Remember Redirect only works while rendering the component and not with event handlers
- State updates are reflected in the next render cycle and not immediately. So you should depend in the function param only to redirect

```
  const handleDetails = name => {
    setdetails(name);
    if (name) {
      return history.push(`/detilaing/${name}`);
    } else {
      return history.push(`/`);
    }
  };
```

- Paging component can receive data from params and render it or use it to fetch the data and render. this way data will be seemlessly rendered on refreshes on each route

```
import React from "react";

export default function PAGING({ match }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{match.params.ability}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-babbage-emobx?file=/src/PAGING.js)

Now suppose you want to pass more than a string to the Paging component and you do not wish to persist it on refresh, you can pass on the data using state.

```
history.push({
   pathname: '/detilaing',
   state: { detail }
})
```

and use it in page.js from location

```
export default function PAGING({ location }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{location.state && location.state.detail}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Updated the link. Sorry

Comment: If you notice onview buton click its opening on the same page

Comment: Yeah because the Route is rendered on the same page along with the view button. Now whereever you render the Route that place the Paging component will be rendered

Comment: But how can i land to new page any idea?

Comment: How do you want it to look. Can you share a screenshot of design or somelayout. Because when you click on View button you are already on a new page as you can see fro mthe url

Comment: I just added the screenshot , if it open on same page hide other things

Comment: Thanx @Shubham Khatri

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213703/discussion-between-coding-and-shubham-khatri).

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.context.router.push({
     pathname: '/detilaing',
     state: {details: this.state.details}  
 })
```

access state by:

```
  this.props.location.state.details
```